# Read persistance data when app is removed

Tags: android

i wanted to write and read  data into/from a file.

I have searched and founnd these two methods which work perfectly..

```
public void writeToFile(String data,Context context) {
        try {
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput("config.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
            outputStreamWriter.write(data);
            outputStreamWriter.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
        }
    }

    public String readFromFile(Context context) {

        String ret = "";

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = context.openFileInput("config.txt");

            if ( inputStream != null ) {
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String receiveString = "";
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                    stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
                }

                inputStream.close();
                ret = stringBuilder.toString();
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("login activity", "File not found: " + e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("login activity", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

But this file is being deleted when i remove the application from my android device.

Is there any method to save and retrieve data whatever if the user deleted the app ?

Comment: Read here: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files you probably need to create the file in a different position, read about getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() to get a path for files which are not deleted upon app removal

Answer (score 2):

You can't. When removing an app, the files in it's local storage are removed.

You can however save your files in an external directory. That way, they aren't deleted when the user removes the app. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage).